# Accessing Armadillo sparse complex matrix elements

Tags: c++, matrix, complex-numbers, sparse-matrix, armadillo

I have the following function:

```
double Qi(int i) {
    double val = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < Model.buses.size(); j++)
        val += Sol.V[j] * (Y[i, j].real() * sin(Sol.D[i] - Sol.D[j]) - Y[i, j].imag() * cos(Sol.D[i] - Sol.D[j]));

    return Sol.V[i] * val;
}
```

The variable Y is a complex sparse matrix from the armadillo library `SpValProxy<arma::SpMat<std::complex<double> > >`. The problem is that the compiler tells that I cannot access the real or imaginary parts of an specific matrix element.

The error is the following:

> error: ‘class arma::SpValProxy > >’
>   has no member named ‘real’

I have no clue of what to do to access the complex number properties of the complex sparse matrix.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you need to cast `Y` to `arma::SpMat<std::complex<double> >`?

Comment: I don’t think so since the type of Y is precisely that. Y is a sparse matrix where the "cells" are complex numbers. and I cannot access the real or imaginary parts of those complex numbers.

Comment: Unless I've slept through a major change, in the expression Y[i, j], the `i` will simply be discarded and the `j` will be the only index used. Not that that answers the question, but it sort of raises a flag for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SpValProxy is used as an element guard, to capture zero values which are not to be stored in a sparse matrix.

You need to get past the guard like this:

```
std::complex<double> temp = Y(i,j);
```

then access the real and imaginary parts of temp. Alernatively, Change Y to be a const reference to a matrix, which should tell Armadillo to bypass the guard directly.

Also, you have a bug: Y[i,j] doesn't do what you think it does. In C++ only one index is used inside a [] expression. Use Y(i,j) instead.

Comment: So, if I want to access all the items in the sparse matrix, I would need to do a for loop from 0 to the number of elements and call the elements like sp_matrix[i] ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a loop like that for sparse matrices. It's doable for dense matrices, but sparse matrices in essence have internal encoding. When accessing an element at a random location in a sparse matrix, the matrix needs to work out whether there is actually an element there. To bypass this, it's better to use the sparse matrix iterators, which are faster. http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#iterators_mat

Answer (score 2):

This will also work, in a more direct manner:

```
const sp_cx_mat& YY = Y;

// can now access .real() and .imag() directly:
double re = YY(i,j).real();
double im = YY(i,j).imag();
```